# Git command to get all commits of a branch between two tags

Tags: git

We have multiple repositories, let's say R1, R2, and R3. Each repository has multiple branches B1, B2, and B3. We need to generate a list of all the commits between two tags for all the repositories (R1, R2, and R3) for the same branch (B1). I have tried using below git command:

```
git log --all <branch_name> <start_tag>..<end_tag> --pretty=format:"%H, %cn, %ci, %s" > log.csv
```

It generated all the commits of a repository where I am running Git Bash.

When I use it without `--all` clause:

```
git log <branch_name> <start_tag>..<end_tag> --pretty=format:"%H, %cn, %ci, %s" > log.csv
```

It gives me commits between two tags of a repository where Git Bash is run. However, this one gives me commits only for a single repository. I have to run this command in every repository to get all the commits for the same branch.

How to get all commits of all repositories for the same branch? Running multiple commands in a batch by mentioning the repository name should also be fine.

Comment: _"for all the repositories in a branch"_? Do you mean all the branches in a repo (or something else, like all the repos in our BitBucket account)?

Comment: Does your branch ever merge? Also, if the command you tried doesn't do what you want, _what do you want_?

Comment: To get the repository name, simply change the format to include a static text corresponding to your repository name. As for "not giving me the desired output", can you start by telling us what you did get and what was wrong with it, preferably also an example of what you wanted? In general it is much more helpful and easier to answer questions that say "How do I do X?" instead of the more popular ones "I did X, it didn't do what I want, halp?"

Comment: @msanford: I meant all the repositories for the same branch. Let's say, I have multiple repositories: R1, R2, R3. I have multiple branches for each repository: B1, B2, B3. I want all commits of between two tags of R1, R2, R3 for B1.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen: I have updated my question. Let me know if it is still missing some information.

Comment: What is your repository structure? Do you have submodules or multiple remotes?

Comment: Have a look at the `--remotes` option for `git  log`